# Traveling to the Schengen area with a UK visa-rejection stamp, as a citizen of an Annex II country

Tags: schengen, uk, visa-refusals, canadian-citizens

In July 2016 I have been denied a visa to the UK. Now my concern is if it's possible to enter the Schengen area in September for research and sightseeing with a cross stamp in my passport?

I'm a Canadian citizen.

Comment: Are you asking if the UK shares immigration history with other regimes, specifically Schengen? That one can be answered with relative authority. Whether or not you personally will be affected at a border crossing is less certain.

Comment: If you travel to a Schengen country, you can expect to be asked to explain about the cross stamp in your passport. If they don't like your explanation, they can refuse entry.

Comment: If you're a Canadian citizen, why did you apply for a visa to the UK?

Comment: @JonathanReez their other question covers this - discovered to be working illegally on a student visa in the UK, subsequently applied for a T5 and was rejected.

Comment: @Moo I admit I am a freelancer when visiting UK without visa not because i was working on a student visa .Student Visa allows you to work 25hr/week.

Comment: @GayotFow Thank you again ,do you mean i should reach the exact country immigration officer to which am travelling to ? I mean am scared of taking the risk not getting in again ...I want to know the chance and consequence .

Answer (score 3):

As specified in [the Canadian travel advice for France](https://travel.gc.ca/destinations/france) (exemplary for other Schengen countries) you do not need a visa to enter the Schengen area.

> Tourist visa: Not required for stays up to 90 days*

This is not altered by your previous UK visa refusal.
However upon arrival you will have a landing interview which can be anything from a brief look to a lengthy discussion and the outcome can range from admission to refused entry. There is no way predicting that outcome but your denied UK visa is a weak point.
The officer will assume you would want to overstay/work illegaly/do other bad stuff in the Schengen area and it is your job to be able to convince them of the opposite. You will want to have a well-planned touristic itinerary with you, including bookings of accomodation and transport if possible. You mention wanting to go for *"research"* among others which sounds fairly vague to me and might surely lead to plenty of other questions.

Comment: Hi ，Thanks for your opinion ,my trip was entirely smooth after I entered from Italy boarder and left in Netherlands within 3 months period. I did prepared my itinerary and booking of events also accomodation ,but the boarder officer seems to be loose on me ,he passed on me with a warm smile on his face . Thanks god !